# Parsing JSONObject with JSONArray

Tags: android, parsing, arrays, json

Help me please to parse this JSON. I'm trying to get 'JSONObject' first, then `.getJSONArray`*(MainArray)* and from `MainArray` I'm trying to get `secondaryArray` but to no avail.

```
{
"MainArray": [
    {
        "id":"someID",
        "secondaryArray": [
              {
                  "id":"someID"
              },
              {
                  "id":"someID"
              }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I need to get to the `secondaryArray` objects, but I'm new in android and I'm confused in this hierarchy.

Comment: what u tried?.....show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(<JSON>);
JSINArray secondaryArray;
JSONArray mainArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MainArray");
for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = intertopSheuleItemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    secondaryArray= obj.getJSONArray("secondaryArray");
    if (secondaryArray!= null)
        break;
}
```

And then work with `secondaryArray's` objects.

Comment: oO why loop, then break on first occurrence? unoptimized solution

Comment: @Alexander Zhak, whrite pls optimized solution.

Comment: @AskQuestion if "MainArray" and "secondaryArray" appear only once in your json, then see most upvoted answer

Answer (score 3):

U can do like this :

```
JsonArray jsSecondArray = firstJsObj.getJsonArray("MainArray").getJsonObject(0).getJsonArray("secondaryArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this too.

```
public static final String TAG_MAINARRAY="MainArray";
    public static final String TAG_SECONDARYARRAY="secondaryArray";
    public static final String TAG_ID="id";
    public static final String TAG_MAINARRAY_OBJ_ID="id";



        try {
JSONObject json =new JSONObject(<response_String>)
            JSONArray MainArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MAINARRAY);
            for(int MainArray_i = 0; MainArray_i < MainArray.length(); MainArray_i++){
                    JSONObject MainArray_obj=MainArray.getJSONObject(MainArray_i);
                JSONArray secondaryArray = MainArray_obj.getJSONArray(TAG_SECONDARYARRAY);
                for(int secondaryArray_i = 0; secondaryArray_i < secondaryArray.length(); secondaryArray_i++){
                        JSONObject secondaryArray_obj=secondaryArray.getJSONObject(secondaryArray_i);
                    String str_id = secondaryArray_obj.getString(TAG_ID);

                    }
                String str_MainArray_obj_id = MainArray_obj.getString(TAG_MAINARRAY_OBJ_ID);

                }
        } catch (JSONException e){
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(yourJson);
JSONArray mainArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MainArray");
for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.lenght(); i++){
    JSONObject obj = mainArray[i].getJSONObject();
    String id = obj.getString("id");
    JSONArray secondaryArray = obj.getJSONArray("secondaryArray");
    for (int j = 0; j < secondaryArray.lenght(); j++){
        JSONObject innerObj = secondaryArray[j].getJSONObject();
        String innerId = innerObj.getString("id");
    }
}
```